# How to increase the Height of Fragment dynamically based on the size of List View inside it

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` in my layout, and the fragment contains a `ListView`.

Now i add data to my `ListView` dynamically, so `wrap_content` and `match_parent` does not effect its `height`, I use following appracoh to dynamically increase the height of my listView. This method works perfectly on ListViews, but here it fails.

```
  public void setListHeight(ListView listView) {
        DataListAdapter listAdapter= (DataListAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

I can dynamically increase the height of my listView by using the above method, but the height of fragment is still `wrap_content`. I am unable to understand how to increase the height of `Fragment` dynamically, because the `ListView` height is not effecting `Fragment` height,and it still showing only 1 item in `ListView`

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
               class="com.myproject.fragments.fragmentControl"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/fragmentId"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your `setListHeight` doesn't make sens ... it makes LinearLayout from ListView ... also `Adapter.getView` is called at least twice for every item in adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [fragment-android-listview-example](http://www.androidtutorialsworld.com/fragment-android-example/) tutorial.